# Azure App Service plan with Premium storage (SSD)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

My web app is hosted in Azure App Service. Based on the current I/O performance I guess it is not using SSD. Is there an option/roadmap to setup/support SSD for Azure App Service?

Answer (score 3):

Somewhat out of date, but the [Premium V2 App Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/app-service/windows/) have been available with SSDs since July 2017.

> The upgraded Premium plan, Premium v2, features Dv2-series VMs with faster processors, SSD storage and double memory-to-core ratio compared to Standard

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there doesn't seem to be any plan. However I would recommend you to upvote this feature request on UserVoice:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/11699025-more-stronger-app-service-machines